# How to change the letter of page of MS Word reference from S. to P

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to add a reference to MS. Word 2010, and when I edit the reference to put a page I get the following:

```
(Mathis & Jackson, 2008, S. 260)
```

I want to make the S. to P. for Page but cannot find where to set this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question.

- Go to references -> manage source
- Select the reference you want to fix, and click edit.
- In the language, select English.

[image: Print screen -> Edit source language]